# how to change icon color when navigate to another page in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a BottomBar and make them enable to navigate to the other pages using onPressed function like below codes. but after navigating to other page that'd be can't change icon color because I think i made bottomnavigationbar: BottomBar in other page so that the page build BottomBar newly and 'int current Tab=0' is build again..

how can I change the way to can be change icon's color?

--BottomBar--

```
class BottomBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomBar> createState() => BottomBarState();
}

class BottomBarState extends State<BottomBar> {

  int currentTab = 0;

  PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();
  Widget currentScreen = HomePage();
  final List<Widget> screens = [
    HomePage(),
    ShopPage(),
    PeoplePage(),
    WalletPage()
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: 10,
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = HomePage();
                        currentTab = 0;

                      });
                      Navigator.push(
                          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>  HomePage())
                      );
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.home,
                          color: currentTab == 0? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = ShopPage();
                      });
                      Navigator.push(
                          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> const ShopPage())
                      );

                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.shop,
                          color: currentTab == 1? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              //Right Tab Bar Icons
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = WalletPage();
                        currentTab = 2;
                      });
                      Navigator.push(
                          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> const WalletPage())
                      );
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.wallet,
                          color: currentTab == 2? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = PeoplePage();
                        currentTab = 3;
                      });
                      Navigator.push(
                          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>  PeoplePage())
                      );
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.people,
                          color: currentTab == 3? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

--the way I used BottomBar in the other page--

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying this :

```
 return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        extendBody: true,
        body:pageOPtions[selectedPage]
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xff282828),
          currentIndex: selectedPage,  //let's say it's 0
          selectedLabelStyle: cardSecondaryTextStyle,
          unselectedLabelStyle: cardSecondaryTextStyle,
          selectedItemColor: const Color(0xffc8332c),
          unselectedItemColor: const Color(0xff707070),
          selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Color(0xffc8332c)),
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              selectedPage = index;
            });
          },
          items: [
            const BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Color(0xff707070),
                size: 16,
              ),
              activeIcon: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Color(0xffc8332c),
                size: 22,
              ),
              label: 'Profile',
            ),
            const BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.history,
                color: Color(0xff707070),
                size: 16,
              ),
              activeIcon: Icon(
                Icons.history,
                color: Color(0xffc8332c),
                size: 22,
              ),
              label: 'Orders',
            ),
```

where `pageOptions` can be your screens like :

```
 final pageOptions = [
    const GeneralSettingsForm(),
    const OrdersAndDelivery(),
  ];
```